# Ubuntu 19.04 fail to suspend on idle

Tags: suspend, power-management, 19.04

I have a desktop machine running ubuntu 19.04

until a couple of days ago, while the machine goes idle correctly, after the latest software upgrades, it doesn't run correctly:

Now, the system first shut down the screen, then, while attempting to suspend the machine, it fails and the machine continue running.

But, if I move the mouse or press a key on the keyboard, nothing happens.

The only way to resume is to force the suspend status with the power button, then the machine can be resumed.

As I didn't make any change on the machine, I suppose that the incorrect behavior derive from the latest software upgrade.